# Copy file to folder before build csproj

Tags: c#, csproj

I can not figure out how to copy a file into another folder before the build is done. It is a `Xamarin.Forms` project.

My current approach is:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <CrossFiles Include="..\path\$(Configuration)\droid\AndroidManifest.xml;" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <Copy SourceFiles="@(CrossFiles)" DestinationFolder="Properties/" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

It is on the bottom of the file directly above `</Project>`.

This approach seems to have no effect. What I am doing wrong ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check out the msdn blog entry about [build events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-specify-build-events-csharp?view=vs-2017). Basically these are commands that are executed either before or after building a project

Comment: Are you sure `..` is locating the correct path? Try removing '/' after Properties and omitting the SkipUnchangedFiles attribute. I would omit the semicolon as well.

Answer (score 1):

try add the output path varaible to the destination folder:

```
DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\Properties"
```